# Python Twisted TCP socket how to set TCP_NODELAY (Disable Nagle's algorithm)?

Tags: python, algorithm, sockets, tcp

I have a real-time multiplayer game in continued development (It's currently live on the app store: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/blewp!-eat-or-be-eaten-mmo/id996122625?mt=8), and I use both TCP and UDP for sending real-time messages (TCP for messages that need reliability, like players dieing), and my server-side is written in python, using Twisted for the server. I often have to send small packets quickly, and disabling packet queuing (Nagle's algo.) should help get packs to arrive faster.

I did some research on twisted, and found that this setting is under abstract.FileDescriptor in twisted (documentation link: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.1.0/api/twisted.internet.tcp.Connection.html)

I'm quite new to Twisted, so could someone tell me how to actually call this setting, for a TCP Protocol server? I couldn't find where the FileDescriptor is accessable. :(

A line of example code would be nice, advice is always appreciated ;)

Here is a simple example I made to help explain the question:

```
class TCPProtocol(Protocol):

    def connectionMade(self):
        #add to list of connected clients
        factory.clients.append(self)
        '''HELP HERE PLEASE!!!'''
        '''EG.  self.NO_DELAY=True HOW DO I SET THIS?'''


    def dataReceived(self, data):
        pass

    def sendData(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)



#setup factory and TCP protocol class
factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = TCPProtocol
factory.clients = []
reactor.listenTCP(1959, factory)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Protocol` object has a `self.transport` that is the `FileDescriptor` you're looking for. This code should do what you want:

```
class TCPProtocol(Protocol):

    def connectionMade(self):
        # add to list of connected clients
        factory.clients.append(self)
        self.transport.setTcpNoDelay(True)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this question.